# Clean folder every hour

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I want the Rails server to empty the folder `public/photos` every hour, so that the folder does not get too full. How can I do that (if it's even a possibility)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you have access to crontab in your hosting environment *(ie. **not** heroku)*, you can add the following to your crontab

```
0 * * * * rm -rf /path/to/rails/app/public/photos/*
```

If you're running on Heroku you can use the [Heroku Scheduler](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler) addon by creating a `lib/tasks/scheduler.rake` file within your application containing something like

```
require 'fileutils'

task :clear_photos => :environment do
  FileUtils.rm_rf Dir.glob("#{Rails.root}/public/photos/*")
end
```

You can read the docs at the above link to learn how to configure the scheduler to run this `clear_photos` task hourly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever) gem. It's easy do this kind of work through this gem.

There's even a free [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/164-cron-in-ruby) on this topic.